# Rename ONLY the last column in each dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

I would like to rename the final column in each one of my dataframes which are in a list of dataframes. The new name will be the same for all.

I made code that extracts the last column (below), but none that renames the final column header.

```
List <- lapply(List, function(x) x[,ncol(x)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {names(x) <- c(names(x[-length(x)]), "new_name");x})

#[[1]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear new_name
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4        4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4        4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4        1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3        1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3        2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3        1

#[[2]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear new_name
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4        4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4        4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4        1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3        1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3        2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3        1
```

Or a simpler version as mentioned by @Shree

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {names(x)[ncol(x)] <- "new_name";x})
```

---

We can also use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(lst,. %>% rename_at(ncol(.), ~"new_name"))
```

**data**

```
lst <- list(head(mtcars), head(mtcars))
```